# My Wordpress Website is Slow to Respond on Moving to Another Pages

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress website is suddenly slow to respond when I want to view another pages. For example, if I clicked one link on the menu, it took around 10-15 seconds for the website to move to the page linked. However, when the website responded and move to the page, the content loaded fast. So, I thought it was not about the loading speed of my website. Correct me if I am wrong.

Are there any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is likely **TTFB (time to first byte)** problem - it takes a long time for your server to generate the HTML of the page and send it as an answer to the request. Meanwhile when the HTML is already sent - all the js files and images are loading fast enough, as you described. There's just this "delay between switching pages".

This could be caused by plenty of factors, I recommend reading a profound article to understand all the nuances, like this: https://kinsta.com/learn/page-speed/

But in short, the first and most sure way to cut down your page loading speed with the described situation - use page caching. You can use https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/ free plugin as the first step.

Managed WP hosting with built-in caching would be even better, but prices start from 30$ per month if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please open this link and follow the steps accordingly

https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/ways-to-speed-up-wordpress/